# difference between the prefix "un" and "not"

Tags: negation, semantics, prefixes

is there any plausible way to seperate the semantics of

> undefined - not defined

or

> undetermined - not determined

?

Comment: sorry bout that, gonna edit my question

Comment: Maybe "un-" means "opposite of", while "not" is "negation of".

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing (in every instance I can think of), however the use of the "un" prefix often leads to smoother and more elegant syntax: "The police arrived to find the house unoccupied." or "He thought Jane's comments were rather unkind." The use of "un" also increases flexibility in adding qualification: "Peter was particularly unimpressed by Venice." v "Peter was not impressed by Venice particularly.", etc.

Comment: There could be a case for saying that "undefined" and/or "undetermined" can be used as positive or deliberate actions, as opposed to no actions or intentions occurring. So: "The exact boundaries of the estate are not defined in some sections." v "The exact boundaries of the estate are undefined so that future generations might make a further claim if the opportunity arises."

Comment: Uh, what is your question??

Comment: @Cargill- I +1’d your comment for discerning the distinction, but I see it the opposite way.  “The boundaries are not defined” implies to me that they were deliberately not defined while “the boundaries are undefined” is merely a statement of state and could mean that they are that way due to negligence.

Answer (score 1):

First of all ***"not"*** is not a prefix it is actually an adverb.

In fact prefix ***un*** is added to the front of **adjectives** or **participles** and usual meaning is opposite or not; but ***not*** is used to give the following word or phrase a negative meaning.

***Not*** can be used with verbs, auxiliary verbs, words or phrases when the speaker is correcting them, and noun phrases with an expression of quantity.

think about these examples:

1- He **is not** determined to do ....

2- he is an **un**determined person.

You can see the meaning is different.

Comment: However "determined" in these examples mean different things, rather than the meaning or sense being changed by "un" and "not".  He is not determined to do ..." and "He is undetermined (as) to what to do ..." better compares like with like, it seems to me.